# Unable to create cluster or node pool in the GCP web interface?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have been having the same issue creating clusters or node-pools in K8 from the GCP interface for the past two days. While I can create them from the gcloud terminal the web interface just returns a 'failed to load' error (see screenshot) with no further log traces. Any idea how I can find out what is causing the problem?

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7DzD.png)

Comment: Did you have a look in the Cloud Logging to see if you have more details on the errors?

Comment: I did not see anything in Cloud Logging, but browser network logs were returning a bunch of 404 errors. What finally helped was turning off all background spam/ad/popup blockers I had.